# Subsystem on sshd_config

Tags: networking, unix-socket, sshd

In /etc/sshd/sshd_config , I could see

**Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server**

This specifies the subsystem and its location.

How and when will the subsystem be started?

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

the sftp subsystem is started automatically after ssh login from the ssh client (examples: winscp, scp, filezilla). the sshd daemon "link" the ssh connection with the sftp daemon and create new process. Regards.